# How to prevent user from sharing downloaded file in Flutter

Tags: flutter

I'm working on an online course app where students can view streaming course videos. I also want to add the ability for students to download course videos for offline viewing, but I don't want them to be able to share those videos. Is this possible? If yes, how would I go about it? Thanks in advance for any lights on this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can store those videos on internal application documents directory so that user can not access those files directly.

To get the application documents directory, use `path_provider` package (official plugin by flutter team)

```
 final directory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
```

Comment: And the user has no way of accessing the contents of this directory?

Comment: nothing is bullet proof, user can jail break the device to access any file. But in a normal scenario user can not access it